# DynamoDB M-M Adjacency List Design Pattern - Delete all associations?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, adjacency-list

I'm designing a Table with GSIs using an Adjacency List Design pattern - which would be able for perform all specified Queries and all seems to be working well (if you see any other improvements, please mention them!).

[image: Table Design]

One problem I'm stuck on is how to delete associations. Let's say user deletes a Tag, which is used across multiple pages (where pages are tagged with one or more tags).

What I was hoping to do is just user deleteItem - but it requires whole PrimaryKey = partitionKey + sortKey (if exists) and deletes only ONE item.

BatchWrite would require basically the same - to know the sort key for every association in order to delete it.

If for example I would need to delete "tag-article" I would need to delete three rows:

1. tag itself - PK: tag-article SK: tag-article
2. reference to page-cs-articleId - PK: tag-article SK: page-cs-articleId
3. reference to page-en-article2 - PK: tag-article SK: page-en-article2

Is there any other way of improving the table design which **would allow me to actually delete all associations** (tags) by specifying it's id?

Thank you kindly for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjacency list design pattern requires you to query the GSI and/or table to find everything that is related. Only once you know all the associations can you delete them.